# FileUpload and Button Click refresh page in UpdatePanel

Tags: c#, asp.net, file-upload, triggers, updatepanel

I have big problem with my page in ASP .NET.
I have MasterPage with PlaceHolders like this:

```
<div class="container-fluid">
            <asp:ScriptManager runat="server"></asp:ScriptManager>
            <asp:UpdatePanel runat="server"><ContentTemplate>
                    <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="ContentPlaceholder1" runat="server">

                    </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
                </ContentTemplate></asp:UpdatePanel>

        </div>
```

and second page related with MasterPage with FileUpload and Button controls.

```
<div class="container p-3">
        <div class="row justify-content-md-center">
            <fieldset>
                <div class="text-center p-2">Dodaj nowy typ pokoju:</div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <asp:TextBox ID="typPokojuTextBox" runat="server" CssClass="form-control input-group-lg" placeholder="Typ pokoju"></asp:TextBox>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <asp:TextBox ID="opisPokojuTextBox" runat="server" CssClass="form-control input-group-lg" placeholder="Opis pokoju" TextMode="MultiLine"></asp:TextBox>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <asp:TextBox ID="cenaPokojuTextBox" runat="server" CssClass="form-control input-group-lg" placeholder="Cena pokoju"></asp:TextBox>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <asp:Label runat="server" ForeColor="Green" CssClass="mr-3">Wybierz zdjęcie pokoju: </asp:Label>
                    <br />
                </div>

                <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel" runat="server">
                    <ContentTemplate>
                        <asp:FileUpload runat="server" ID="okladkaFileUpload" />
                        <asp:Button ID="uploadTypButton" runat="server" CssClass="btn btn-primary" Text="Upload" OnClick="uploadTypButton_Click"></asp:Button>
                        <asp:Label runat="server" CssClass="custom-control-label" ID="dodajTypLabel"></asp:Label>
                    </ContentTemplate>
                    <Triggers>
                        <asp:PostBackTrigger ControlID="uploadTypButton" />
                    </Triggers>                  
                </asp:UpdatePanel>  
                <div class="form-group text-center">
                </div>
                <div>
                </div>
            </fieldset>
        </div>
    </div>
```

I've tried everything that comes to my mind. I need to use UpdatePanel because I do not want to refresh the page after clicking the button. Maybe I have some error in the code included in UpdatePanel?

I tried such solutions as:
AsyncPostBackTrigger
PostBackTrigger
AJAX AsyncFileUpload

The above solution works but this is the most annoying thing that is the refresh of the page.

Please help me, I do not have any ideas how to correct the code.

EDIT:

```
     <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel" runat="server">
   <ContentTemplate>


            <fieldset>
                <div>
                ///textbox and label's
                </div>
                        <asp:FileUpload runat="server" ID="okladkaFileUpload" />
                        <asp:Button ID="uploadTypButton" runat="server" CssClass="btn btn-primary" Text="Upload"  onchange="Change(this);" OnClick="uploadTypButton_Click"></asp:Button>
                        <asp:Label runat="server" CssClass="custom-control-label" ID="dodajTypLabel"></asp:Label>

            </fieldset>

                        </ContentTemplate>
            <Triggers>
               <asp:PostBackTrigger ControlID="uploadTypButton"  />
           </Triggers>

 </asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Answer (score 0):

To use a FileUpload or HtmlInputFile control inside an UpdatePanel control, set the postback control that submits the file to be a PostBackTrigger control for the panel. The FileUpload and HtmlInputFile control can be used only in postback scenarios.

Here's the [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386454.aspx)

If you include FileUpload control within UpdatePanel and use AsyncPostbackTrigger, the HasFile property of the FileUpload Control will always be false.

Comment: Rajeev, thank you for your answer. So it should look like in EDIT post?

Comment: @adamo, Glad to help, could you please accept the answer if it helped?

Comment: Rajeev, Can I change this code in order to make it work properly? I still have a problem :( Will the removal of HasFile solve the problem?

Comment: If you're okay with full postback, your code looks fine. If you still want it to be async postback, there are other options like AsyncFileUpload control.

Comment: Unfortunately, I need it to work in such a way that after clicking uploadButton the whole page does not refresh. I tried to use the AsyncFileUpload control but I do not know how to apply it as I want to send the image only after clicking the button.